# Text deletion in EditText stops because of setSelection()

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'd like to highlight some words in my `EditText` with the following code:

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        private boolean ignoreChange = false;
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            int cursorPosition = mEditText.getSelectionStart();
            if(!ignoreChange){
                //Highlight words
                ignoreChange = true;
                mEditText.setText(spannable);
                mEditText.setSelection(cursorPosition);
                ignoreChange = false;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        }
    });
```

So, there are two problems:

-While I am touching delete button on the keyboard, it deletes only one char instead of deleting all chars till I am touching the button.

-The text input is very slow.

Both problems as I see occur because of `setSelection(..)`. I use `setSelection(..)` because `setText(..)` sends cursor to the begining of `EditText`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the solution for the problem was put the code from
`onTextChanged(...)` method into `afterTextChanged(...)`.
This way we can edit `EditText`'s text straight via editable object, so we don't need to call `mEditText.setText(...)` and `mEditText.setSelection(...)`

Comment: This will trigger the text changed event again

Comment: Yes, but only afterTextChanged()

Comment: Thanks, I use editable.replace(0, editable.length, myNewText) and selection and delete work fine!